# how I get Boolean value from mysql in JSP?

Tags: mysql, eclipse, jsp, jdbc, xampp

Well I am working on a JSP project, I am done with uploading section and get file name and directory to my Database, Now I want to Notify Admin that a new file has been uploaded, for this I give a column name delivered where I store 0 (false) in bool, So I want to get the total number of false value and show them in my Admin Dashboard .... 
Here My Admin section code..

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ page import="java.sql.Statement,
 java.sql.DriverManager,
 java.sql.Connection,
 java.sql.ResultSet" %>

    <%  
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance ();
       Connection c =            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/fyp?","root","");
       Statement   s = c.createStatement();
       String sql ="SELECT * FROM `notify-admin` WHERE Delivered='0'";
         s.executeUpdate(sql);

         ResultSet  resultset= s.executeQuery(sql);

            if(!resultset.next()) {
                out.println("Sorry, could not find Any Admin Record From  Database. ");
            } else {

         %>
    <button type="button" class="primary">New Documents <span class="badge"> <% while (resultset.next()){ resultset.getString(3); %></span>
      <%} %>

   <% 


       } 
   %>
    </button>
```

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of changes you need to make:

1. Remove the below statements:

   `Statement   s = c.createStatement();`

   `s.executeUpdate(sql);`
2. If you want total number of values then use the below query:

   `"SELECT count(*) as count FROM notify-admin WHERE Delivered='0'"`

Once you get the `resultSet` object, you can do `resultset.getInt("count")` to get the value.

Comment: if I removed `Statement   s = c.createStatement();`

`s.executeUpdate(sql);`
then what I give to resultset to execute ?

Comment: You are already doing `executeQuery` that returns a result set.

Comment: yap I am doing it but its link with the statement and that statement with with database, I got error when I removed them.

Comment: You are actually trying to do an `executeUpdate` with select statement. Ideally it should be update or delete statement. Don't know why we were executing same statement twice.

Comment: oh Got it about Resultset executing, still confuse what to do with Statement.

Comment: You don't need Statement at all. You can declare PrepareStatement with `connection.prepareStatement(sql)` and call `executeQuery` on that prepared statement object.

Comment: `Statement   s = c.createStatement();  String sql ="SELECT count(*) as count FROM notify-admin WHERE Delivered='0'"; ResultSet  resultset= s.executeQuery(sql);`

can you edit this one :) coz I am not getting how to do

Comment: Have a look at this example: http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/

Answer (score 0):

```
Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/fyp?","root","");
String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `notify-admin` where " ;
PreparedStatement prest = con.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet rs = prest.executeQuery();
while (!rs.next()) {
       out.println("Sorry, could not find Any Admin Record From Database. ");
   }
System.out.println("Number of records: " + records);
con.close();
```

try this one 
this will count how many record in database thats delivered id is o mean false

Comment: from this you get total number of user that deliver id is false